# Combining functions and consumers with double-column notation

Tags: java-8, functional-interface

I often use the double-colon notation for brevity.

I am writing the following method that takes a short list of entities, validates them, and saves back to database.

```
@Override@Transactional
public void bulkValidate(Collection<Entity> transactions)
{
    Consumer<Entity> validator = entityValidator::validate;
    validator = validator.andThen(getDao()::update);
    if (transactions != null)
        transactions.forEach(validator);

}
```

I'd like to know if there is a shorthand syntax avoiding to instantiate the `validator` variable

Following syntax is invalid ("The target type of this expression must be a functional interface")

```
transactions.forEach((entityValidator::validate).andThen(getDao()::update));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *could* do that, but you would need to cast explicitly...

```
 transactions.forEach(((Consumer<Entity>)(entityValidator::validate))
                             .andThen(getDao()::update));
```

The thing is that a method reference like this `entityValidator::validate` does not have a type, it's a *poly* expression and it depends on the context.

You could also define a method to combine these Consumers:

```
@SafeVarargs
private static <T> Consumer<T> combine(Consumer<T>... consumers) {
    return Arrays.stream(consumers).reduce(s -> {}, Consumer::andThen);
}
```

And use it:

```
transactions.forEach(combine(entityValidator::validate, getDao()::update))
```